# How to get file upload image to display on certain URL Node JS

Tags: node.js, url, browser

I am new to Node JS and I have successfully managed to create a page that allows file uploads and it displays the image in the browser.  The only issue I am having is that it displays to a page with the file name appended onto the end of the URL like this: localhost:8888/tmp/car.png
I want to be able to see it in my browser with a URL like this:
localhost:8888/car

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!!!!!!

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express()

 /// Include the express body parser
 app.configure(function () {
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

var form = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>" +
"<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" +
"<input type='file' name='image'/>" +
"<input type='submit' /></form>" +
"</body></html>";

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(form);

  });

 /// Include the node file module
 var fs = require('fs');

 /// Post files
  app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {

    var imageName = req.files.image.name

    /// If there's an error
    if(!imageName){

        console.log("There was an error")
        res.redirect("/");
        res.end();

    } else {

      var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/fullsize/" + imageName;

      /// write file to uploads/fullsize folder
      fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {

        /// let's see it
        res.redirect("/uploads/fullsize/" + imageName);

      });
                }
        });
   });

         app.listen(8888)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
express.static('uploadPath')
```

for: `localhost:8888/car.png`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.